# Jquery Passing Table Rows Between Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, crud

I have a simple grid layout I wrote using jQuery. I have one problem. I want to allow only one edit row at a time. So I keep track of current editing row and reset it on next edit button is clicked. Still when I click edit for next time it allows me edit. completeEdit works fine cause I am also calling it from cancel button by passing current row.

```
 var currentRowEdit =null;

   $(tableid + ".edit").live('click', function(event) {
            currentRowEdit = $(this).parent().parent();
            editRow(currentRowEdit);
    });


function editRow(row){
        if(currentRowEdit!=null){
            completeEdit(currentRowEdit);               
        }              
           $(row).find(".save").show();
           $(row).find(".cancel").show();
           $(row).find(".edit").hide();

    }

function completeEdit(row){             
         $(row).find(".save").hide();
          $(row).find(".cancel").hide();
         $(row).find(".edit").show();              
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are calling completeEdit and editRow on same row. you should call completeEdit on previous and editRow on new

```
 var currentRowEdit =null;

   $(tableid + ".edit").live('click', function(event) {
            completeEdit(currentRowEdit);
            currentRowEdit = $(this).parent().parent();
            editRow(currentRowEdit);
    });


function editRow(row){



           $(row).find(".save").show();
           $(row).find(".cancel").show();
           $(row).find(".edit").hide();

    }

function completeEdit(row){
         if(row==null){
           return;

        }
         $(row).find(".save").hide();
          $(row).find(".cancel").hide();
         $(row).find(".edit").show();    

    }
```

Comment: Thanks . I made that change . But still the problem remains .

Answer (score 1):

```
function completeEdit(row){
   $(row).find(".save").hide();
   $(row).find(".cancel").hide();
   $(row).find(".edit").show();   
   currentRowEdit = null; // reset the currentRowEdit
}
```

#### According to comment

Your code is not hiding the the `.save` and `.cancel` button. Because, if you look at you code flow will notice, after the `completeEdit()` function you're using `.show()` method for those button.

As a result, your buttons hide when `completeEdit()` done but after that when rest of the code of `editRow()` executed, then those buttons again become visible.

Comment: @SoneshDabhi please check the update and hope you will find clues.